# Converting 32-bit unsigned little endian to integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, 32-bit

I have an array of 4 bytes. 32-bit unsigned little endian.

```
[ 123, 1, 0, 0]
```

I need help converting this to an integer. I tried below with no luck:

```
let arr = [ 123, 1, 0, 0 ];
let uint = new Uint32Array(arr);
console.log('INT :', uint);
```

Comment: 8 bytes? where are the other 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

If you *know* your browser is also little endian (almost always true these days), then you can do it like this:

```js
const bytes = new Uint8Array([123, 1, 0, 0]);
const uint = new Uint32Array(bytes.buffer)[0];
console.log(uint);
```

If you think your browser might be running in a big endian environment and you need to do proper endian conversion, then you do this:

```js
const bytes = new Uint8Array([123, 1, 0, 0]);
const dv = new DataView(bytes.buffer);
const uint = dv.getUint32(0, /* little endian data */ true);
console.log(uint);
```